# Probability theory - A homogeneous Markov chain, probabilities for no more than $n$ steps

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, markov-chains

Let a sequence $X_0, X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be a homogeneous Markov chain of states of some system at discrete instants of time 0, 1, 2, ...,
and let $\{S_1, \ldots, S_N\}$ be the set of states of the system.

Let $\pi^0=(\pi_1, \ldots, \pi_N)$ be the vector of initial probabilities, that is $\pi_i=P(X_0=S_i)$, $i=\overline{1, N}$, $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \pi_i=1$.

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ ($i=\overline{1, N}$, $j=\overline{1, N}$) be the transition probability matrix, that is $a_{ij}=P(X_n=S_j| X_{n-1}=S_i)=P(S_i \to S_j)$, $i=\overline{1, N}$, $j=\overline{1, N}$; $\sum_{j=1}^{N} a_{ij}=1$ $\forall i=\overline{1, N}$.

Let $A^{(k)}=(a_{ij}^{(k)})$ ($i=\overline{1, N}$, $j=\overline{1, N}$) be the probability matrix transition for $k$ steps, that is $a_{ij}^{(k)}=P(X_n=S_j| X_{n-k}=S_i)=P(S_i \to S_j \, \text{in } \, k \, \text{steps})$, $i=\overline{1, N}$, $j=\overline{1, N}$; $\sum_{j=1}^{N} a_{ij}^{(k)}=1$ $\forall i=\overline{1, N}$.

It is known that
$a_{ij}^{(k)}=\sum_{l=1}^{N} a_{il}^{(m)}a_{lj}^{(k-m)}$, $i=\overline{1, N}$, $j=\overline{1, N}$;

$A^{(k)}=A^k$;

in particular, $a_{ij}=a_{ij}^{(1)}$, $i=\overline{1, N}$, $j=\overline{1, N}$.

Let $\pi^{(n)}=(\pi_{1}^{(n)}, \ldots, \pi_{N}^{(n)})$ be the probability vector for the states of the system at time $n$, that is $\pi_{i}^{(n)}=P(X_n=S_i)$, $i=\overline{1, N}$; $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \pi_{i}^{(n)}=1$.

In particular, $\pi_{i}=\pi_{i}^{(0)}$, $i=\overline{1, N}$;

$\pi^0=\pi^{(0)}$.

There are well-known formulae for finding the components of the vector $\pi^{(n)}$:

$P(X_n=S_j)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} P(X_{n-1}=S_i)P(X_n=S_j| X_{n-1}=S_i)$, $j=\overline{1, N}$;

$\pi_{j}^{(n)}=\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_{ij}\pi_{i}^{(n-1)}$, $j=\overline{1, N}$;

$\pi^{(n)}=A^T \pi^{(n-1)}$;

$P(X_n=S_j)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} P(X_{n-k}=S_i)P(X_n=S_j| X_{n-k}=S_i)$, $j=\overline{1, N}$;

$\pi_{j}^{(n)}=\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_{ij}^{(k)}\pi_{i}^{(n-k)}$, $j=\overline{1, N}$;

$\pi^{(n)}=(A^k)^T \pi^{(n-k)}=(A^T)^k \pi^{(n-k)}$;

$P(X_n=S_j)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} P(X_0=S_i)P(X_n=S_j| X_0=S_i)$, $j=\overline{1, N}$;

$\pi_{j}^{(n)}=\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_{ij}^{(n)}\pi_i$, $j=\overline{1, N}$;

$\pi^{(n)}=(A^n)^T \pi^0=(A^T)^n \pi^0$.

I am interested in two questions.

1) How to find the probability of the transition from the state $S_i$ to the state $S_j$ in no more than $k$ steps, that is $P(S_i \to S_j \, \text{in no more than } \, k \, \text{steps})$?

2) How to find the probability of the system to be in the given state for no more than $n$ steps, counting from the initial time moment, that is $P(X_0=S_i \, \text{or } \, X_1=S_i \, \text{or } \, \ldots \, \text{or } \,X_n=S_i)$?